# SQL query for block entering value between range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with below data.

```
MinValue.        MaxValue
------------------  --------------------
1.                        10
11.                       15
16.                       20
```

When I try to enter new values in this table with existing range; it should validate.
For eg: if I try to enter 5 as MinValue and 10 as max value then it should validate and block. Because  1 to 10 is already in the table. If it is 21 to 25 then it should allow to save new row with 21 and 25.

How to create an SQL query for this validation?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great place to start. You should view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your example data is weird because it already violates your defined constraints as far as I understand the question. Please change this first to better show what you want to achieve.

Comment: Block saving if new values are between this range

Comment: So now an editor has changed your information to compensate for the original overlapping rows. Whether this is helpful or not remains to be seen - especially if your existing rows are as you originally posted. That's the problem with editing - it can add confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches.  The more obvious method is a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_insert_trigger ON t INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM inserted i JOIN
                   t
                   ON t.minvalue <= i.maxvalue and
                      t.maxvalue >= i.minvalue
             )
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('You have attempted to insert overlapping values')
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END 
   ELSE BEGIN
       INSERT INTO t (minValue, maxValue)
           SELECT minValue, maxValue
           FROM inserted;
   END;  
END;
```

The second method would be a `check` constraint with a user-defined function.